# How to get completed sales with rest API in magento 2?

Tags: api, magento2, rest-api

Github issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1578

It works for `processing` status, however I get an error for `completed` or `closed`

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ufkm720fkvqix2v0dhhs8xvpp3g4lmcc" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 366814d0-e058-7b89-c896-5670fb4fadb9" 'http://magento2.app/index.php/rest/V1/orders?criteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=status&criteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=processing'
```

result: `{"items":[]}`

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ufkm720fkvqix2v0dhhs8xvpp3g4lmcc" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 366814d0-e058-7b89-c896-5670fb4fadb9" 'http://magento2.app/index.php/rest/V1/orders?criteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=status&criteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=closed'
{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-55b7959277fcb"}
```

The log is as following:

```
[2015-07-28 14:45:38] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-55b7959277fcb; 
Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Reflection/TypeCaster.php on line 34' in /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest.php(191): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /home/vagrant/laravel-root/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

Can you point me in a right direction? Do you think it's a magento 2 bug?

Thank you

Magento 2 Rest API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/restApi/restCollection/Magento/Sales/Service/V1/OrderList/orderList.html

Token-based authentication: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: Magento 2 has open bug tracker and better to place issues on it

Comment: @KAndy added to github issue queue

Comment: @VladVinnikov, how can i inoke SOAP Service? I tried fallowed by http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html but unable to get result Could you please suggest me. see my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76569/class-magento-testframework-testcase-webapi-adapter-soap-not-found-in-magento

Comment: @magentotwo why use soap, when rest is available

Comment: @VladVinnikov, Could you please give/suggest me with example(with code)? ex: customer service

Comment: with rest you could use a simple curl http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php I prefer to use guzzle http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ see examples above

Comment: @VladVinnikov, i have tried above link examples, it's returning WSDL code. can you please give me a example how to invoke magento 2 api?

Comment: @VladVinnikov, see my thread i have fallowed your example, but unable to get result suggest me how to invoke magento 2 api? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83151/call-to-a-member-function-customeraccountmanagementv1createaccountrequest-on-s

Comment: @magentotwo Can you create a new question with code sample that didn't work?

Comment: @VladVinnikov, see my thread newly created http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83151/call-to-a-member-function-customeraccountmanagementv1createaccountrequest-on-s